# JSON.stringify() removing data from data model in React

Tags: reactjs

I have two versions for the same logic. Below are the two codes:

```
  /*Code 1*/
this.state.dataModel[0].route.routeLine = this.props.routeLine.join(' ');

/*Code 2*/
this.setState(prevState => {
    const newDataModel = [...prevState.dataModel];
    newDataModel[0].route.routeLine = this.props.routeLine.join(' ');                        
    return {dataModel: newDataModel};
                    });
/* Common Code */
let finalData = { ...this.state.dataModel[0], 
                   hasLocationChanged: this.state.isLocationEditedForConsSeg };
let data = JSON.stringify(finalData)


console.log('Stringify Data ',JSON.stringify(data))
```

When I use `Code 1` the object is converted to JSON strings without data loss. But if I use `Code 2` I am loosing data in JSON strings when using `JSON.stringify()`.But according to my understanding of react `Code 1` is not the correct way to mutate state

Below is the `finalData` in JSON object:

```
{
   "layer": 1,
   "layerName": "ConstructionSegment",
   "layerId": 7384,
   "agencyId": 79,
   "lpModel": {
      "lastProjectType": 2,
      "lastProjectSurf": 2,
      "gravelType": 0,
      "gravelTreatment": 0,
      "bitType": 1,
      "concrType": 0,
      "astType": 0,
      "compType": 0,
      "lastProjectYear": 2002,
      "lpDepth": 7,
      "totalDepth": 7,
      "lastProjectMile": "0",
      "comment": "",
      "lastProjectYearEst": 0,
      "lpDepthEst": 0,
      "totalDepthEst": 0
   },
   "bModel": {
      "topBaseType": 3,
      "topBaseDpt": 23,
      "topBaseYear": 1973,
      "topBaseTrt": 6,
      "bottomBaseType": 2,
      "bottomBaseDpt": 23,
      "bottomBaseYear": 0,
      "bottomBaseTrt": 1,
      "fabric": 0,
      "subgradeStrength": 100,
      "subgradeStrengthType": 5,
      "lastSGImpYear": 0,
      "subgradeTrt": 1,
      "topBaseTypeEst": 0,
      "topBaseDptEst": 0,
      "topBaseYearEst": 0,
      "bottomBaseTypeEst": 0,
      "bottomBaseDptEst": 0,
      "bottomBaseYearEst": 0,
      "subgradeStrengthEst": 0,
      "lastSGImpYearEst": 0
   },
   "xModel": {
      "laneWidth": 4,
      "numLanes": 2,
      "rtShoulderTotal": 5,
      "rtShoulderPaved": 0,
      "gradingYear": 1973,
      "curbs": 0,
      "inslopeRatio": 0,
      "paveSloughWidth": 0,
      "sloughRatio": 0,
      "edgelineTrt": 0,
      "centerlineTrt": 0,
      "medianType": 0,
      "medianWidth": 0,
      "rightOfWay": 100,
      "sectionOwner": 2,
      "gradingYearEst": 0
   },
   "maintenance": {
      "blade": [],
      "regravel": [],
      "reshape": [],
      "spotRep": [],
      "dustControl": [],
      "surfacing": [],
      "crackSeal": [],
      "patching": [],
      "striping": [],
      "cpr": [],
      "crackSealConcrete": [],
      "reApplyAst": []
   },
   "pavementcondition": {
      "PlannedProjType": 0
   },
   "route": {
      "id": 12804,
      "start": "47.04905, -95.722035",
      "end": "47.107359, -95.721154",
      "routeLength": "4.03",
      "routeArray": [
         "47.04906,-95.72206",
         "47.06001,-95.72184",
         "47.06281,-95.72179",
         "47.07266,-95.7216",
         "47.07647,-95.72154",
         "47.07991,-95.72149",
         "47.08224,-95.72154",
         "47.08528,-95.72169",
         "47.08749,-95.72178",
         "47.08846,-95.72179",
         "47.09029,-95.72181",
         "47.09236,-95.72178",
         "47.09425,-95.72172",
         "47.09729,-95.72154",
         "47.10185,-95.721",
         "47.10291,-95.72095",
         "47.10738,-95.72119"
      ],
      "routePointArray": [
         [
            47.04906,
            -95.72206
         ],
         [
            47.06001,
            -95.72184
         ],
         [
            47.06281,
            -95.72179
         ],
         [
            47.07266,
            -95.7216
         ],
         [
            47.07647,
            -95.72154
         ],
         [
            47.07991,
            -95.72149
         ],
         [
            47.08224,
            -95.72154
         ],
         [
            47.08528,
            -95.72169
         ],
         [
            47.08749,
            -95.72178
         ],
         [
            47.08846,
            -95.72179
         ],
         [
            47.09029,
            -95.72181
         ],
         [
            47.09236,
            -95.72178
         ],
         [
            47.09425,
            -95.72172
         ],
         [
            47.09729,
            -95.72154
         ],
         [
            47.10185,
            -95.721
         ],
         [
            47.10291,
            -95.72095
         ],
         [
            47.10738,
            -95.72119
         ]
      ],
      "startPoint": [
         [
            47.04905,
            -95.72204
         ]
      ],
      "endPoint": [
         [
            47.10736,
            -95.72115
         ]
      ],
      "waypoints": [],
      "isPolyLine": false,
      "hwyNum": "34",
      "segDesc": "",
      "routeLine": "47.04906,-95.72206 47.06001,-95.72184 47.06281,
                   -95.72179 47.07266,-95.7216 47.07647,
                   -95.72154 47.07991,-95.72149 47.08224,-95.72154 47.08528,
                   -95.72169 47.08749,-95.72178 47.08846,-95.72179 47.09029,
                   -95.72181 47.09236,-95.72178 47.09425,
                   -95.72172 47.09729,-95.72154 47.10185,-95.721 47.10291,
-95.72095 47.10738,-95.72119"
   }
}
```

I can see the data `routeLine` in the `console.log()` statement if I use `Code 1` but I cannot see the data `routeLine` in the `console.log()` if I use `Code 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing it becasue setState is asynchronous. If you call `this.setState` and soon after you read `this.state` you'll notice that it's not immediately updated.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826057/react-this-setstate-not-updating-a-variable) for further details please and [setState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

**edit1**: I created a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-heisenberg-pv01y?file=/src/App.js) for you. Check code in App.js, you'll se 4 click functions and a logState function. click1 and click2 do what you did in your original post, click3 and click4 propose a solution to overcome the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. I have used click 3 to overcome the problem. Thank you again for the solution. So now I understand why my setState was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `routeLine` is a string: `"47.04906,-95.72206 47.06001,-95.72184 47.06281"`, not an array as you might think. You need to first convert it to an array, and then apply a `join()`:

`this.state.dataModel[0].route.routeLine.split(' ').join()`. You might need to revise your state and make sure you are parsing data according to your expectations.

Comment: Yes `routeLine` is converted to string after using the `join()` operation which is performed on array. I am not understanding why `JSON.stringify()` is removing that from the JSON strings if I use `Code 2` instead of `Code 1`